# Replace non-zero values with 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id    col1   col2   col3
123   10     0      82
456   0      90     16
987   0      0      0
```

I'd like to replace all non-zero values in the columns that are not id with 1.

I've tried:

```
df.col1 = df.where(df.col1 != 0, 1)
```

But that replaces the non-zeroes with 1s and the zeros with the id.

Then I tried setting a new df to this function:

```
df2 = df.col1 = df.where(df.col1 != 0, 1)
```

And that works except it changes the id column to a 1 where it changed the non-zero value to a 1.

Any help troubleshooting the codes that are not working or another approach would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean that are not id with 1?

Comment: I mean I'd like to replace all non-zero values in columns that are not the id column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`astype`

```
df

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123    10     0    82
456     0    90    16
987     0     0     0

df.astype(bool).astype(int)

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123     1     0     1
456     0     1     1
987     0     0     0
```

Or, create a mask with `gt`:

```
df.gt(0).astype(int)

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123     1     0     1
456     0     1     1
987     0     0     0
```

If `id` isn't the index, *set it first*!:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

---

**Option 2**
`mask`

```
df.mask(df > 0, 1)

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123     1     0     1
456     0     1     1
987     0     0     0
```

---

**Option 3**
`df.where` (note the difference from your approach)

```
df.where(df == 0, 1)

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123     1     0     1
456     0     1     1
987     0     0     0
```

Similar solution with `np.where`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > 0, 1, 0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

     col1  col2  col3
id                   
123     1     0     1
456     0     1     1
987     0     0     0
```

Comment: @sharatpc Thanks, I'd be interested to know what works best.